# C# validate using public void bool whether the User Input meets criteria

Tags: c#

I have a c# program (new to it) in public static void Main(string[])
and I ask the user to input a single UPPERCASE char followed by two numbers.

I then want to validate this using a bool method, then return to the Main after it's validated.

The user input is fine but when it gets to validation, it only returns false. (Answer should be A88 or F83 etc)

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter type starting with a Capital Letter with 2 numbers: ");
            string letter = To.Upper(Console.ReadLine());
            int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            while (letter.Length > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter type containing 1 with a capital letter: ");
                letter = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            while (numbers>2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter TWO numbers");
                numbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(letter, numbers);
public static void bool isValid() 
     {

          if (letters,numbers.Length >3)
            {
              return False
             }
          else
          {return True
          }
      }
```

then it should go back to the Main(string[])

How do I put together letters, numbers together and based on that, validate it as a boolean, then move back to the main method where it would then do a calculation (that part, I'm fine with)

Answer (score 0):

You want to first handle the user input in `Main` in a loop. Once you are satisfied that user input is handled, put in a call to a method which accepts the **current** user input and then does the *validation* and returns `bool`.

Something like this

```
Main()
{
bool isInputValid = false
string userInput;


while (isInputValid == false)
   {
      userInput = Console.ReadLine();
      isInputValid = IsUserInputValid(userInput);
   }
 Console.Writeline($"Congrats {userInput} is valid");

 } 

// Static is needed within the main code file since it is not in a class. 
public static bool IsUserInputValid(string input)
{
     if (input.Length < 3)
     {
       Console.Writeline("Must be three characters");
       return false;
     }
    
    // More validation checks failures to report on 
     if (...)
     {
       Console.Writeline("...");
       return false;
     }

    // If at the end where all validations pass just return true
    return true;
}
```

Note `Main` is the program and is only called by the OS during its running. One does not call it within the code. So the loop asking for user input is in main to keep it alive.